# must build Spark with Hive (spark 1.5.0)

Tags: python, maven, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

downloaded spark 1.5.0 pre-built and run via pyspark this simple code

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('Alice', 1)]
sqlContext.createDataFrame(l).collect
```

Yields error:

```
15/09/30 06:48:48 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MResourceUri" is tagged as "embedded-only" so do
es not have its own datastore table.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\bigdata\spark-1.5\spark-1.5.0\python\pyspark\sql\context.py", line 408, in createDataFrame
    jdf = self._ssql_ctx.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())
  File "c:\bigdata\spark-1.5\spark-1.5.0\python\pyspark\sql\context.py", line 660, in _ssql_ctx
    "build/sbt assembly", e)
Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred
 while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o28))
```

so tried to compile it myself

```
c:\bigdata\spark-1.5\spark-1.5.0>.\build\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin\mvn  -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests -Phive -Phive-t
```

hriftserver clean package

but still get the same error on the compiled version.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You forgot to import SqlContext and it has to wrap spark Context

Comment: You can try to run `sqlContext._get_hive_ctx()` and look at the logs you get just after. Perhaps you will find something in there that points you in the right direction (for me it was a problem with two concurrent pyspark applications trying to initialize the temporary Derby database).

Answer (score 1):

add these line after importing the row

```
from pyspark import  SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext( 'local', 'pyspark')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

Comment: No, the pyspark script creates a SQLContext (actually it will attempt to create a HiveContext) for you. You shouldn't create one yourself in this case.